# SQL Error: extraneous input ')' expecting AS near '<EOF>'

Tags: sql, date, hive, casting

I'm receiving following error when I try to get month_diff

```
extraneous input ')' expecting AS near '<EOF>'
```

Here is SQL code

```
months_between((cast(min(bs.cpd_dt)) as date), cast(bs.first_prd_cpd_dt as date)) as month_diff
```

Can anyone help me where is the bug?

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis after `min(bs.cpd_dt)` ... remove it and the error should go away.

Comment: When I remove, it throws me another error `extraneous input ')' expecting AS near '<EOF>'`

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are unbalanced, in multiple places.  Use this version:

```sql
months_between(
    cast(min(bs.cpd_dt) as date),
    cast(bs.first_prd_cpd_dt as date)
) as month_diff
```

Or, as a single line:

```
months_between(cast(min(bs.cpd_dt) as date), cast(bs.first_prd_cpd_dt as date)) as month_diff
```

Comment: The above code returns me an error `Not yet supported place for UDAF 'min'`

Comment: You need to figure out why `min()` is not available here...I would have expected it would be.